# Position of \only within a \tabular

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
  \only<1>{only 1}
  \only<2>{only 2}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
```

It compiles, but curiously the position changes slightly between 2 slides. Does anyone know how to keep the same position while using `\only`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppress the spurious blank space after `\only<1>{only 1}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
  \only<1>{only 1}%
  \only<2>{only 2}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tabular environment will look at all rows before deciding on column widths. For the first slide, there is only one row to look at. You can use `\visible` to have all rows present on each slide, but just not shown.